# Obtener valores de una propiedad en C#

Tags: c#, class, reflection

Muy buenas, ando trasteando con la api del LoL. Un MOBA en línea.
Resulta ser que **quiero obtener todos los id's de los campeones del juego con sus respectivos nombres**, pero cada campeon es un objeto, de manera que no se me ocurre forma humana de poder obtener todos los IDS sin ponerlos línea a línea.

Por ejemplo:

```cs
Champion campeones;
string id = "";
id = campeones.data.Taric.id;
id = campeones.data.Akali.id;
```

Hay alguna forma de obtener todos los objetos de campeones.data y luego acceder a sus IDS y Nombres? Había pensado esto:

Algo así:

```cs
Champion campeones;
string[] champsId = new string[141];
string[] champsName = new string[141];

for(int i = 0; i < 141; i++) {
    champsId[i] = campeones.data.*.id;
    champsName[i] = campeones.data.*.name;
}
```

Sustituyendo el * por el nombre del objeto. Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las clases deben de ser muy parecidas a algo como lo que sigue:

```
class Target
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Nombre { get; set; }
}

class Data
{
   public int idData { get; set; }
   public Target Taric { get; set; }
   public Target Akali { get; set; }

   public Data()
   {
      Taric = new Target();
      Akali = new Target();
   }
}


class Champion
{
   public Data data { get; set; }

   public Champion()
   {
       data = new Data();
   }
}
```

Tomando en cuenta eso, podrías obtener todas las propiedades de *data* utilizando *reflection* de la siguiente manera:

```
   Champion campeones = new Champion();

   int numeroPropiedades = campeones.data.GetType().GetProperties().Count();

   for (int i = 0; i < numeroPropiedades; i++)
   {
       var propertyInfo = campeones.data.GetType().GetProperties()[i];

       // Filtras los tipos porque podría haber propiedades
       // que no sean las que deseas (en este caso idData que es un entero)
       if(propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(Target))
       {
           var property = propertyInfo.GetValue(campeones.data, null) as Target;
           var id = property.Id;
           var name = property.Nombre;
        }
    }
```

Toma en cuenta que estoy dando por hecho que las propiedades de tu interés (las que contienen id y name) son del mismo tipo (en mi ejemplo Target) si no fuera así, dentro del if tendrías que utilizar una condición que correspondiera a tu realidad para que no vaya a ocurrir una Exception. También, tendrías que validar los null, etc.

Utilicé un for para que vieras como funcionaba *reflection* pero podrías utilizar un foreach y saltarte algunos pasos:

```
   Champion campeones = new Champion();

   foreach (var propertyInfo in campeones.data.GetType().GetProperties())
   {
       // Filtras los tipos porque podría haber propiedades
       // que no sean las que deseas (en este caso idData)
       if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(Target))
       {
           var property = propertyInfo.GetValue(campeones.data, null) as Target;
           var id = property.Id;
           var name = property.Nombre;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Carlos. Después de muchas horas buscando, encontré un sumario con todos los campeones con sus propiedades en formato JSON en un array. De todas formas agradezco tu respuesta y tomo nota de ello para el futuro. Muchas gracias! :)